# iphone offline webapp, how to handle storage of data?

Tags: javascript, json, html, caching, mobile

I'm trying to build a simple iphone webapp. It's only purpose is to process a form, store that data in JSON, and display it on another page. My question is: how do I store this data offline, so that it is not cleared when I relaunch my webapp?

My goal is to visit my app in mobile safari, add it to my homescreen, and start using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use localstorage API of html5 or better use websql. Both are persistent.  If you want to create a native app from html5/js code use apache cordova otherwise no need.